# Media queries don't work well on different size screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I have used media queries to design some parts in my website. For example, I have setted certain settings for 1920 px width screen resolutions, but they look different on my 15" laptop and my 25" desktop screen. They look way different.
How can I make them look pretty much the same?

```css
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #bluetitle {
    padding-right: 357px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1600px) {
  #bluetitle {
    padding-right: 235px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 1601px) and (max-device-width: 1919px) {
  #bluetitle {
    padding-right: 310px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h5 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">
  <p dir="rtl"><span id="bluetitle">Title<font color="#dff2f6">.</font></span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.938em; font-weight: 600;"></span></p>
</h5>
```

Here's the website: [mayabarber.co.il](http://mayabarber.co.il)

Here's a screenshot of how it looks like on 15" (1920 width resolution):
[image]

Here's a screenshot of how it looks like on 25" (1920 width resolution- that's how it's supposed to look):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion would be to use percentages when defining `padding-right`. That will allow more consistency across different screen sizes.

Comment: I agree with @HamzaAhmad use  percentages

Comment: px is a relative unit. 1px in 24" screen is not same as 1px in 15" screen. Use percentages instead for consistency.

Comment: For some reason when I added percentage units nothing has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try by adding this meta tag to the html document? 
And try to give % values for paddings / margings

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the media queries in that case !
Just set : text-align: right on the title container and keep the padding right on the title if you want to.

```
#bluetitle{
    padding-right:...px;
}

p{
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: But I still want it to look good on different resolutions, not just the 1920px width

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this CSS with the `Inspect element` on your website and it seems to be alright.

Try setting your CSS like so:

```
#bluetitle {
    background-color: #dff2f6;
    padding-right: 1%; /* You can edit this as per your needs */
}
```

IMO, you do not need the @media queries as in the test, your website was looking fine without the @media queries.

Comment: I just added that and nothing has happened, I even added !important

Comment: @media (min-width: 1920px) {
#bluetitle {
padding-right: 40% !important;}
}

I needed the media queries because on different screen resolutions it looked different.

Comment: @RoziBuber Did you try setting it without the media queries? Defining `padding-right` percentage means it will keep the same distance from the right no matter what screen size